# using mock side_effect in python to mock a function

Tags: python, mocking

I am trying to use the side_effect feature in python mock, to completely replace the call to a particular function, with a call to another function. Now the two functions take different sets of arguments, and I wasnt sure how to pass the arguments to the side_effect.

My sample code is like this:

```
import mock

def func1(arg1):
    print arg1

def func2():
    print 'original function'

@mock.patch('func2', side_effect=func1)
def func():
    func2()

func()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm confused. . . Why would you patch a function with another function with a _different_ signature?

Comment: Well i am trying to do this because, the function i am essentially mocking is interacting with a 3rd party system. The patched function, I intend to have, is providing data similar to the 3rd party system in the same format, but the data is accessible using different arguments. Hope this helps clear the confusion?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't define how call `func1` when no args are supplied there is no way to answer better than...

```
@mock.patch('func2', side_effect=lambda:func1("Hei... I don't know what you want to do!")
def func():
    func2()
```